# How to custom InputStream to JSch channel.setInputStream method?

Tags: java, scala, jsch

I want use a custom data source, for example data from a remote socket, to explicit setting InputStream in JSch, such as:

```
class MySocket {
  def onReceive(f: Byte => Unit) = ???
}
val socket: MySocket = ...
socket.onReceive(byte => {
  //put byte to MyCustomInputStream and get by JSch channel.
  ...
});

val channel = session.openChannel("shell").asInstanceOf[ChannelShell]
channel.setInputStream(MyCustomInputStream) 
channel.setOutputStream(System.out)
channel.connect(6 * 1000)
....
```

How to implement `MyCustomInputStream` class?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some test, I find it should block read thread if no input here, snippet like this:

```
object MyInputStream extends InputStream {
  val readLock = new AnyRef
  var readFlag = false
  var data = ArrayBuffer.empty[Byte]
  data.append("ls\n".map(_.toByte): _*)
  new Thread(() => {
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000)

    data.append("pwd\n".map(_.toByte): _*)
    readied = true
    lock.synchronized(lock.notify())

  }).start()

  var dataIndex = 0

  val lock = new AnyRef
  var readied = true
  override def read(): Int = {
    if(!readied) {
      lock.synchronized(lock.wait())
    }
    val rst = if(dataIndex < data.length) {
      val a = data(dataIndex)
      dataIndex += 1
      a
    }
    else {
      readied = false
      -1

    }


    println("read - " + rst)

    rst
  }
}
```

Notice: `data` should be refine with `ByteBuffer` or other variable data structure.